# Normalising the exponential solution of the infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am having trouble normalising the wave function of the Schrodinger equation for the infinite well. Using the sin and cos approach I get $A=\sqrt\frac{2}{L}$, but using exponentials I get A=$\sqrt\frac{-1}{2L}$ which I know to be incorrect.
I have $\psi(x)=Ae^{ikt}-Ae^{-ikt}$.
Is it correct using $\psi^*\psi$ that the condition should be:$\int^L_0A^2e^{2ikx}+A^2e^{-2ikx}-2A^2 dx=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Both the calculation are correct. I think you are confused because you have the constant to 'A' in both cases. If you simplify the exponential case you will get the same wavefunction sqrt(2/L)*sin(x/L).

Comment: Is there a way to keep it in the exponential form without simplifying?

Comment: note that $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: and note that $\sqrt{-1}=i$. now it should be clear

Answer (score 0):

$$ \psi(x)=Ae^{ikt}-Ae^{-ikt} = 2Ai \sin{(kt)}$$

$$ \psi(x)^* = - \psi(x)$$

$$ 1 = \left[ (-i) \cdot i \right] 4A^2 \int_0^L sin^2(kx) dx  = -\left[ (-i) \cdot i \right] 4A^2 ( L/2 - sin(kL)*cos(kL)/2k - 0/2 + sin(0)*cos(0)/2k )  =  -\left[ (-i) \cdot i \right] 4A^2/k ( L/2 - 0 - 0 + 0 ) = 2 A^2 L$$ 
You get the desired result $A = \sqrt{2/L}$.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be 4 instead of 2 at the start? And are you using the trig relation $sin^2(x)=\frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}$ ?

Comment: @caleb Sorry I did the calculation hastily you are right about the first part I edited my answer. I used $\int sin²(ax) dx = t/2 - sin(2ax)/4k$ and $sin(2x) = 2cos(x)sin(x)$